# How to apply same CSS property without overriding and multiple times using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

How to apply same CSS property without overriding and multiple times using jquery?

```
$(function() {

  $("#hello").css({

    // Is there a way to apply both of these instead of having the second override the first?

    "background-image" : "-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #444444),color-stop(1, #999999))",
    "background-image" : "-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999)"

  });
```

});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate each 'directive' with a `;`.

```
$("#hello").css({
    "background-image" : "-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #444444),color-stop(1, #999999));-moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999)"
});
```

Alternatively, put it into a single CSS class, and do it this much prettier and manageable way:

```
.gradient {
    -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #444444),color-stop(1, #999999));
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999);
}


$("#hello").addClass("gradient");
```

Comment: Go with the CSS class.  It definitely will help with manageability in the long run.

Comment: I think there was a problem with a missin paren after the last color-stop property in my above answer. I have fixed it.